# What is context in _.each(list, iterator, [context])?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, this

I am new to underscore.js. What is the purpose of `[context]` in `_.each()`? How should it be used?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

The context parameter just sets the value of `this` in the iterator function.

```
var someOtherArray = ["name","patrick","d","w"];

_.each([1, 2, 3], function(num) { 
    // In here, "this" refers to the same Array as "someOtherArray"

    alert( this[num] ); // num is the value from the array being iterated
                        //    so this[num] gets the item at the "num" index of
                        //    someOtherArray.
}, someOtherArray);
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/a6Rx4/

It uses the number from each member of the Array being iterated to get the item at that index of `someOtherArray`, which is represented by `this` since we passed it as the context parameter.

If you do not set the context, then `this` will refer to the `window` object.

---

**Extras:**

To answer the `What's the advantage of that? Why not just refer to someOtherArray[num] rather than this[num]?` upvoted question found in the comments below, let's move the anonymous `iteratee` callback into a function for easy re-use:

```js
const someOtherArray  = ["name","patrick","d","w"];
const yetAnotherArray = ["what","goes","here","?"];

function alertStr(num){
    alert( this[num] );
}

_.each([1, 2, 3], alertStr, someOtherArray);
_.each([1, 2, 3], alertStr, yetAnotherArray);
```

You can see how the `this` reference allows us to re-use the `iteratee` function across multiple `_.each` calls with different `context` values. This would not work if we had the `someOtherArray` hardcoded inside the `iteratee`.

Comment: What's the advantage of that?  Why not just refer to `someOtherArray[num]` rather than `this[num]`?

Comment: @csjacobs24: It's common to have a set of reusable functions that wouldn't have access to the local variable scope. Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Rx4/745/

Comment: This answer does answer the question, but it would be better if it provided examples of how this can be useful.

Answer (score 50):

`context` is where `this` refers to in your iterator function. For example:

```
var person = {};
person.friends = {
  name1: true,
  name2: false,
  name3: true,
  name4: true
};

_.each(['name4', 'name2'], function(name){
  // this refers to the friends property of the person object
  alert(this[name]);
}, person.friends);
```

Answer (score 8):

The context lets you provide arguments at call-time, allowing easy customization of generic pre-built helper functions.

some examples:

```
// stock footage:
function addTo(x){ "use strict"; return x + this; }
function pluck(x){ "use strict"; return x[this]; }
function lt(x){ "use strict"; return x < this; }

// production:
var r = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var words = "a man a plan a canal panama".split(" ");

// filtering numbers:
_.filter(r, lt, 5); // elements less than 5
_.filter(r, lt, 3); // elements less than 3

// add 100 to the elements:
_.map(r, addTo, 100);

// encode eggy peggy:
_.map(words, addTo, "egg").join(" ");

// get length of words:
_.map(words, pluck, "length"); 

// find words starting with "e" or sooner:
_.filter(words, lt, "e"); 

// find all words with 3 or more chars:
_.filter(words, pluck, 2);
```

Even from the limited examples, you can see how powerful an "extra argument" can be for creating re-usable code. Instead of making a different callback function for each situation, you can usually adapt a low-level helper. The goal is to have your custom logic bundling a verb and two nouns, with minimal boilerplate.

Admittedly, arrow functions have eliminated a lot of the "code golf" advantages of generic pure functions, but the semantic and consistency advantages remain.

I always add `"use strict"` to helpers to provide native `[].map()` compatibility when passing primitives. Otherwise, they are coerced into objects, which usually still works, but it's faster and safer to be type-specific.

Answer (score 6):

### Simple use of _.each

```js
_.each(['Hello', 'World!'], function(word){
    console.log(word);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Here's [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/u3rdnvps/) that could use `_.each`:

```js
function basket() {
    this.items = [];
    this.addItem = function(item) {
        this.items.push(item);
    };
    this.show = function() {
        console.log('items: ', this.items);
    }
}

var x = new basket();
x.addItem('banana');
x.addItem('apple');
x.addItem('kiwi');
x.show();
```

Output:

```
items:  [ 'banana', 'apple', 'kiwi' ]
```

Instead of calling `addItem` multiple times [you could use underscore](https://jsfiddle.net/vb0oqb7L/) this way:

```
_.each(['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'], function(item) { x.addItem(item); });
```

which is identical to calling `addItem` three times sequentially with these items. Basically it iterates your array and for each item calls your anonymous callback function that calls `x.addItem(item)`. The anonymous callback function is similar to `addItem` member function (e.g. it takes an item) and is kind of pointless. So, instead of going through anonymous function it's better that `_.each` avoids this indirection and calls `addItem` directly:

```
_.each(['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'], x.addItem);
```

but this won't work, as inside basket's `addItem` member function `this` won't refer to your `x` basket that you created. That's why you have an option to pass your basket `x` to be used as `[context]`:

```
_.each(['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'], x.addItem, x);
```

### Full example that uses _.each and context:

```js
function basket() {
    this.items = [];
    this.addItem = function(item) {
        this.items.push(item);
    };
    this.show = function() {
        console.log('items: ', this.items);
    }
}
var x = new basket();
_.each(['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'], x.addItem, x);
x.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

In short, if callback function that you pass to `_.each` in any way uses `this` then you need to specify what `this` should be referring to inside your callback function. It may seem like `x` is redundant in my example, but `x.addItem` is just a function and could be totally unrelated to `x` or `basket` [or any other object, for example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbvmazmp/):

```js
function basket() {
    this.items = [];
    this.show = function() {
        console.log('items: ', this.items);
    }
}
function addItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
};

var x = new basket();
_.each(['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'], addItem, x);
x.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

In other words, you bind some value to `this` inside your callback, or you may as well use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) directly like this:

```
_.each(['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'], addItem.bind(x));
```

> how this feature can be useful with some different underscore methods?

In general, if some `underscorejs` method takes a callback function and if you want that callback be called on some member function of some object (e.g. a function that uses `this`) then you may bind that function to some object or pass that object as the `[context]` parameter and that's the primary intention. And at the top of underscorejs documentation, that's exactly what they state: [The iteratee is bound to the context object, if one is passed](http://underscorejs.org/#collections)

Answer (score 4):

As explained in other answers, `context` is the `this` context to be used inside callback passed to `each`.

I'll explain this with the help of source code of relevant methods from [underscore source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html)

The definition of `_.each` or `_.forEach` is as follows:

```
_.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
  iteratee = optimizeCb(iteratee, context);

  var i, length;
  if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
    for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
      iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
    }
  } else {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    for (i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
      iteratee(obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```

Second statement is important to note here

```
iteratee = optimizeCb(iteratee, context);
```

Here, `context` is passed to another method `optimizeCb` and the returned function from it is then assigned to `iteratee` which is called later.

```
var optimizeCb = function(func, context, argCount) {
  if (context === void 0) return func;
  switch (argCount == null ? 3 : argCount) {
    case 1:
      return function(value) {
        return func.call(context, value);
      };
    case 2:
      return function(value, other) {
        return func.call(context, value, other);
      };
    case 3:
      return function(value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, value, index, collection);
      };
    case 4:
      return function(accumulator, value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, accumulator, value, index, collection);
      };
  }
  return function() {
    return func.apply(context, arguments);
  };
};
```

As can be seen from the above method definition of `optimizeCb`, if `context` is not passed then `func` is returned as it is. If `context` is passed, callback function is called as

```
func.call(context, other_parameters);
          ^^^^^^^
```

`func` is called with [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which is used to invoke a method by setting `this` context of it. So, when `this` is used inside `func`, it'll refer to `context`.

```js
// Without `context`
_.each([1], function() {
  console.log(this instanceof Window);
});


// With `context` as `arr`
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
_.each([1], function() {
  console.log(this);
}, arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

You can consider `context` as the last optional parameter to [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) in JavaScript.