# What does the context parameter do in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [underscore.js _.each(list, iterator, [context]) what is context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946456/underscore-js-eachlist-iterator-context-what-is-context)

So in the context of this forEach function in underscore.js:

```
// The cornerstone, an `each` implementation, aka `forEach`.
// Handles objects with the built-in `forEach`, arrays, and raw objects.
// Delegates to **ECMAScript 5**'s native `forEach` if available.
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  if (obj == null) return;
  if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
    obj.forEach(iterator, context);
  } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
    for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (i in obj && iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
    }
  } else {
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (_.has(obj, key)) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

What is the parameter *context* and how is it used?

Comment: [underscore.js _.each(list, iterator, context) what is context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946456/underscore-js-eachlist-iterator-context-what-is-context)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sets the `this` value *(the calling context)* of the iterator function that was passed.

```
iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj);
      //         ^---right here
```

JavaScript's `.call` and `.apply` methods let you invoke a function with the `this` value of the function you're calling set to the first argument you provide.

So if I do...

```
var obj = {foo:"bar"};
func.call(obj);
```

...the value of `this` inside `func` will be the `{foo:"bar"}` object.

So if you provide that argument, underscore uses it as the first argument to `.call` when invoking the function you passed as seen above.

Comment: I understand this in practice, but still find the Underscore source a little confusing.  Based on the code `iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj)` I find it unclear what happens when no `context` is passed.  Am I missing a conditional where `context` is set to `obj` if no `context` is present?

Comment: @i_made_that: No, there's no such condition. If `context` was not provided, then it will be `undefined`, which means the value of `this` in the function will be the global object if not in strict mode, or `undefined` if it is in strict mode.