# "The iterator is bound to the context object."

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

The Underscore.js documentation says:

> **_.each(list, iterator, [context])**
>
> Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iterator function. **The iterator is bound to the context object, if one is passed.** Each invocation of iterator is called with three arguments: (element, index, list). If list is a JavaScript object, iterator's arguments will be (value, key, list). Delegates to the native forEach function if it exists.

```
_.each([1, 2, 3], alert);
=> alerts each number in turn...
_.each({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3}, alert);
=> alerts each number value in turn...
```

What does the bolded text above mean? Can someone provide an example that would explain it?

Comment: related: [underscore.js \_.each(list, iterator, \[context\]) what is context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946456/underscore-js-eachlist-iterator-context-what-is-context)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that, inside your iterator function, the value of `this` will be what you pass as the `context` argument.

For example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
function iterator(el, i, list) {
    console.log(this)
}
_.each(arr, iterator, arr); // will log the whole array 3 times
```

This is useful if you want to pass an object method as the iterator, and that method uses `this`. Example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var myObj = {
    foo : 5,
    addFoo : function(el, i, lst) {
       console.log(el + this.foo)
    }
};

// This will log NaN 3 times, because 'this' inside the function
// will evaluate to window, and there's no window.foo. So this.foo
// will be undefined, and undefined + 1 is NaN   
_.each(arr, myObj.addFoo);

// This, on the other hand, works as intended. It will get the value
// of foo from myObj, and will log 6, then 7, then 8
_.each(arr, myObj.addFoo, myObj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KpV5k/

Comment: Great example. Makes total sense, thanks for the explanation.