# Why/How does a lodash "[iteratee=_.identity] (Function)" in _foreach have a 'mystery' third param?

Tags: foreach, underscore.js, lodash

I am getting the hang of lodash.js for the first time today and have discovered that you can access the 'value' 'index' and 'list' within the iterator function.

I came across this when using the _.foreach function.

For example:

```
_.forEach(oMyArray, function(value, index, list){
    ...
})
```

However the [API](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) specifies only 2 params "n" and "key" when dealing with objects.

Why no mention of the third?

Comment: The API shows three: `_.forEach(collection, [iteratee=_.identity], [thisArg])`

Comment: possible duplicate of [underscore.js \_.each(list, iterator, \[context\]) what is context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946456/underscore-js-eachlist-iterator-context-what-is-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?  Your API link has three arguments listed right there:

> The iteratee is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments:
>   (value, index|key, collection)

Comment: I am referring to the second param which is a function.