# Better way to transform a collection using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to simply replace the invalid date with an empty string. I'm iterating through an array of objects, but whenever I try to use `_.each()` I get lost. If someone could show me a way to iterate through all the `fieldsToCheck` items in my list, that would be rad.

```
massage.removeBadDates = function(data){
  var fieldsToCheck = [
    "partsLeadTime",
    "statusDate",
    "targetDate",
    "revisedTargetDate",
    "quoteDate",
    "dispositionDate",
    "serviceDate",
    "finalDate",
    "receivedDate"]
  var newData = []
  _.map(data, function(value, index, list){
    newData.push(value)
    //single
    if (list[index].partsLeadTime == "1900-01-01T00:00:00"){
      newData[index].partsLeadTime = ""
    }
  });
  return newData
};
```

Comment: official documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#each SO example of `_.each` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4946497/443900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much want something like this:

```
_.each(fieldsToCheck(function(field) { 
   if (list[index][field] == "1900-01-01T00:00:00") {
    newData[index][field] = ""
  }
});
```