# Unable to pass extra argument with UnderscoreJS's each function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to pass an additional object named `modelObj` to underscore's `_.each` function where as I'm not getting the context inside the loop.

My code goes like this,

```
showHideBudget: function(contentObj, modelObj){ 
   _.each(contentObj.find('.budgetSec'), function(item){ 
       // ===> Unable to reference modelObj here <===

       budgetFlag = true;
       return;
    }, modelObj)
 })
```

Can someone help?

**Edit - Here is what I've made it to work.**

Finally found what went wrong, It seems I need to pass both `this` and `modelObj` to make it work, (like this).

```
showHideBudget: function(contentObj, modelObj){ 
   _.each(contentObj.find('.budgetSec'), function(item){ 
       // ===> Unable to reference modelObj here <===

       budgetFlag = true;
       return;
    }, modelObj, this)
 })
```

Comment: Does it tell you it's undefined?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: Do you pass `modelObj` as context to `_.each`? (brackets doesn't match)

Comment: @barbsan My bad. That was a typo, Corrected now.

Comment: @DavidR from your edit you should be able to access `modelObj` using `this`

Comment: @barbsan Thanks!, Tried using `this` it shows all the defined functions and global variables except my modelObj

Comment: Have you tried accessing `modelObj` without passing it as context? Are you sure that `modelObj` before `_.each` call is defined?

Comment: @barbsan Indeed it exists!

Comment: Atlast found what went wrong, It seems I need to pass `this` along with `modelObj`, will update the post accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way instead. You should pass the object to the `_.each`

```
showHideBudget: function(contentObj, modelObj){ 
   _.each(contentObj.find('.budgetSec'), function(item){     
       budgetFlag = true;
       return;
    }, modelObj);
 }
```

Comment: I tried that way too (Updated my post also), no luck though.

Comment: @DavidR [it does work tho](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Rx4/1706/) ... Also updating your question with my answer makes it seem like I copied what you posted in your question, please update the OP with an `EDIT` next time :)

Comment: Oops!. Sorry about that. Will ensure going forward!. :-)

Comment: I tried the way given in your fiddle, only local scoped varibles are getting passed that way, function arguments are not!.

Comment: @DavidR they do [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Rx4/1709/) :P Are you able to change the way you define the function?

Comment: Atlast found what went wrong, It seems I need to pass this along with modelObj, will update the post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Great, happy you found the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, that third argument is what `this` is bound to within your iteratee function. You should be able to get the reference to modelObj through `this` that function that's called for each element of the result of `contentObj.find('budgetSec')`.

Reference: [What is context in _.each(list, iterator, [context])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946456/what-is-context-in-eachlist-iterator-context#4946497)

Comment: (I didn't downvote). Tried using `this` it shows all the defined functions and global variables except my `modelObj`

Comment: Does this post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946456/what-is-context-in-eachlist-iterator-context#4946497

Comment: Nice catch. However only local scoped varibles are getting passed that way, function arguments are not!. Strange!!!

Comment: That is odd... Get anywhere with that info then or is it off the mark?

Comment: Atlast found what went wrong, It seems I need to pass this along with modelObj, will update the post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Oh great! Perhaps some 'up-vote' love? haha. In all seriousness, glad you got to a solution.

Comment: Did mate! Thanks for exploring along with me! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Happy to explore.